# LDAP filter to deny a user in Gitlab

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I saw question how to grant access to **SPECIFIC** users in LDAP settings of Gitlab. But is there anyway to deny a specific user by user filter in LDAP. 
For example, I want, not to allow project mails to Gitlab. So what i have to do? 
My project 
LDAP uid : `cn=projetname,ou=projectmail,ou=company users,dc=company,dc=local`

Comment: I searched and found on a [documentation](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4515) that (!(cn=username))

Comment: You can post a detailed answer, and accept your own answer: that will help others :)

Comment: Well done. +1 on your answer (and thank you for the link to the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to deny or not to include specific user is `(!(cn=username))`.

For more syntax related issues about LDAP: [Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515)